# Clojure re-seq regex with unexpected result

Tags: regex, clojure

I am having a bit of trouble figuring out the right regex for the following:

I have an input file that I am trying to chunk up in groups based on keyword expressions. Here is an example of the file (let's call this case 1):

```
Foo: B
  "This is instance B of type Foo"
  Bar: X
  etc.

Foo: C
  "This is instance C of type Foo"
  Bar: Y
  etc.
```

The following regex:

```
#"(?s)(Foo:)(?:(?!Foo:).)*"
```

works like a charm and produces my expected result of:

```
(["Foo: B\n  \"This is instance B of type Foo\"\n  Bar: X\n  etc.\n\n"
  "Foo:"]
 ["Foo: C\n  \"This is instance C of type Foo\"\n  Bar: Y\n  etc.\n\n\n"
  "Foo:"])
```

However, if someone adds a colon to the commented 'Foo', it goes funky and results in:

```
(["Foo: B\n  \"This is instance B of type " "Foo:"]
 ["Foo:\"\n  Bar: X\n  etc.\n\n" "Foo:"]
 ["Foo: C\n  \"This is instance C of type Foo\"\n  Bar: Y\n  etc.\n\n\n"
  "Foo:"])
```

If, in testing, I remove `Foo: C and it's content` from the input and change the regex to:

```
"(?s)(Foo:)(?:(?!\"Foo:\").)*"
```

I get the expected result:

```
(["Foo: B\n  \"This is instance B of type Foo:\"\n  Bar: X\n  etc.\n\n\n\n"
  "Foo:"])
```

Adding `Foo: C` back into the mix, however, it no longer respects the boundary and results in:

```
(["Foo: B\n  \"This is instance B of type Foo:\"\n  Bar: X\n  etc.\n\nFoo: C\n  \"This is instance C of type Foo:\"\n  Bar: Y\n  etc.\n\n\n\n"
  "Foo:"])
```

I've tried this, to no avail: `#"(?s)(Foo:)(?:(?!Foo:|\"Foo:\").)*"` to name a few thousand unsuccessful gyrations.

I appreciate any help. The intent is to go with the regex to do the chunking of the file.

**Current Solution**
Moved away from `regex` as just too nuanced to deal with the simple chunking I needed. First solution was a loop/recur situation with a few (too many) conditionals and mutating atom as the accumulation map.

I have been hankering to do something specific with `reduce` and, while maybe not the best application, I learnt it in this exercise and dropped excessive code lines.

```
(def owl-type-map
    {
     "Prefix:"               :prefixes
     "AnnotationProperty:"   :annotation-properties
     "Ontology:"             :ontology
     "Datatype:"             :data-types
     "DataProperty:"         :data-properties
     "ObjectProperty:"       :object-properties
     "Class:"                :classes
     "Individual:"           :individuals
     "EquivalentClasses:"    :miscellaneous
     "DisjointClasses:"      :miscellaneous
     "EquivalentProperties:" :miscellaneous
     "DisjointProperties:"   :miscellaneous
     "SameIndividual:"       :miscellaneous
     "DifferentIndividuals:" :miscellaneous
     })

  (def owl-control (reduce #(assoc %1 (second %2) nil) {:current nil} owl-type-map))

  (def space-split #(s/split (str %) #" "))

  (defn owl-chunk
    "Reduce ready function to accumulate a series of strings associated to
    particular instaparse EBNF productions (e.g. Class:, Prefix:, Ontology:).
    owl-type-map refers to the association between owl-type (string) and EBNF production"
    [acc v]
    (let [odex  (:current acc)
          stip  ((comp first space-split) v)
          index (get owl-type-map stip odex)
          imap  (if (= index odex) acc (assoc-in k [:current] index))
          ]
      (assoc-in imap [index] (str (get imap index) v "\n"))))

;; Calling

(reduce owl-chunk owl-control s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a parser generator. Mark Engelberg's [Instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse) is an excellent parsing library for Clojure that sets out to make this an easy choice – the first line of its README is *What if context-free grammars were as easy to use as regular expressions?*

Here's an example of how you could use it to parse your sample input:

```
;; [instaparse "1.3.5"]
(require '[instaparse.core :as insta])

(def p (insta/parser "

S = Group*
Group = GroupHeader GroupComment GroupBody
GroupHeader = #'[A-Za-z]+' ': ' #'[A-Za-z]+' '\n'
GroupComment = ws? '\"' #'[^\"]+' '\"\n'
GroupBody = Line*
Line = #'.*' '\n'
ws = #'\\s+'

"))

(p "Foo: B
  \"This is instance B of type Foo\"
  Bar: X
Foo: C
  \"This is instance C of type Foo\"
  Bar: Y
")
;;=
[:S
 [:Group
  [:GroupHeader "Foo" ": " "B" "\n"]
  [:GroupComment [:ws "  "] "\"" "This is instance B of type Foo" "\"\n"]
  [:GroupBody
   [:Line "  Bar: X" "\n"]]]
 [:Group
  [:GroupHeader "Foo" ": " "C" "\n"]
  [:GroupComment [:ws "  "] "\"" "This is instance C of type Foo" "\"\n"]
  [:GroupBody
   [:Line "  Bar: Y" "\n"]]]]
```

Adding a colon after "Foo" inside the qouted string would not be a problem. (Of course the above grammar is extremely simple – I imagine you may want to start nested groups at `Bar:` etc.)

Comment: Michal, I am using instaparse only at this point I need to chunk up the file prior to feeding it in. Scale issue...

Comment: More specifically, the grammar I am using w/instaparse has ambiguity resulting in exponential parses. By chunking up the input prior it allows me to target specific productions and breeze through parsing. Hope that helps

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. Perhaps you could use a simpler "chunking grammar" for the preprocessing step and then apply your ambiguous grammar to the resulting chunks?

Comment: Eschewed both regex and instaparse and using clojure.string/split approach for chunking.

Comment: added final solution and got my feet wet with reduce. Thanks for your suggestions, as always.